# Sonarqube Eclipse plugin not working in incremental analysis mode

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have installed sonareclipse plugin 3.4 in eclipse Juno version.
I have set sonar.analysis.mode=incremental in preview analysis properties.
But when I analyze the project in eclipse it shows all the issues and not just new issues.

SonarQube server version is 5.1.

Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, analysis in Eclipse is happening in "incremental" mode, so you don't need to specify the `sonar.analysis.mode` property.

Also, the Eclipse plugin always report every issue found in your code, may it be a new one (= you've just introduced it) or an existing one. As described in the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Working+with+SonarQube+in+Eclipse), the new ones are highlighted in yellow so that you can't miss them.

There's no way to hide existing issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to filter only new issues in Eclipse? Also we have around 2,000 issues out of which only first 100 are displayed in eclispe, how can we see all the issues?

Comment: Yes, as it is described in the documentation (see the "SonarQube Issues" part), you can filter new issues in the "Issues" view thanks to the "New Issue" attribute.